# Where do I add large amounts of resources to android project?

Tags: java, android

I am making my first app for android on android studio

I have to include a bunch of Gifs with my app to be displayed at different times
Gifs are total 500mb at the moment and I am going to have to add more soon, so there will be over 1 gig of gifs
At the moment i have dumped all my gifs into the res/drawable folder and i access them using R.id.gifname and display them in a gifImageView.
When i generate a signed APK with android studio the APK size is around 500mb which I've looked up and seen is far too large for google play

My question is whether or not I am taking the right approach to storing all this data in my application and whether or not an uploaded bundle will separate data in the res folder from the code in the APK. Is my approach alright or should I be placing all my gifs somewhere else in android studio?

Comment: Do you need offline access? If not then you can host the gifs online and link them in your app.

Comment: See here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files

Comment: @ZUNJAE I've considered hosting but I would much rather have offline accessibility

Comment: @Henry I cannot make enough sense of the instructions on this page. As I said this is my first android project and I am struggling with this step a bit. I am looking for a kind of simple step-by-step walkthrough showing how these expansion files can be added to my project.